# Prevent odd break line in pagenotes

Tags: formatting, memoir, endnotes, pagenote

Using `memoir` class, `pagenotes` package. Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: odd breakline]

Number 6 should follow the rest of the text, hence be in the following page.

This is the code I'm using:

```
% Document size 
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt,titlepage,openright]{memoir}
\setstocksize{216mm}{154mm}
\settrimmedsize{215mm}{153mm}{*}
\settrims{1mm}{1mm}
\setulmarginsandblock{20mm}{22mm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{22mm}{15mm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\trimLmarks

% Packages
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false,pdfborder=0 0 0}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{caption}[2010/01/03]

% Chapter titles
\usepackage{calc,fourier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\makeatletter
\setlength\midchapskip{7pt}
\makechapterstyle{VZ21}{
  \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\Large\scshape}
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\Large\scshape\centering}
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\huge\bfseries\centering}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{7pt}   % used as indentation on both sides
    \settowidth\@tempdimc{\chaptitlefont ##1}%
    \setlength\@tempdimc{\textwidth-\@tempdimc-2\tabcolsep}%
\chaptitlefont
\ifdim\@tempdimc > 0pt\relax    % one line
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \toprule  ##1\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\else   % two+ lines
\begin{tabular}{
    >{\chaptitlefont\arraybackslash}p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
  \toprule ##1\\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\fi }
}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{VZ21}

% Fix \url width
\renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{\do\/\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z}

% Width
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\begin{varwidth}{40mm}}l<{\end{varwidth}}} %M is for Maximal column
\linespread{1.1}

% Fix pagenotes
\let\pagenote=\endnote
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\prenotetext{%
  \list{}{%
    \setlength\leftmargin{2.3em}%
    \setlength\topsep{-\baselineskip}}
  \item}
\renewcommand*\postnotetext{\endlist\bigskip\medskip}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*\idtextinnotes[1]{#1.\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand*\notenuminnotes[1]{#1.\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\makepagenote

\renewcommand\enoteheading{\chapter {\notesname}%
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\enoteformat{\noindent\theenmark.\hspace{5pt}}
\renewcommand\notesname{Notes}

% Section title
\setsecheadstyle{\large\uppercase}

\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[3]{\section*{#1 #2\ --\ #3}}
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubheadstarred}[3]{\section*{#3}}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{headings}


Text.\pagenote{\emph{US Posts Stronger Solid Growth in July}, Mokoto Rich, 2011. The New York Times.\emph{US Posts Stronger Solid Growth in July}, Mokoto Rich, 2011. The New York Times.\emph{US Posts Stronger Solid Growth in July}, Mokoto Rich, 2011. The New York Times.\\\url{http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/06/business/economy/us-posts-solid-job-gains-amid-fears.html?pagewanted=all}} 
Text.\pagenote{\emph{US Posts Stronger Solid Growth in July}, Mokoto Rich, 2011. The New York Times.\\\url{http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/06/business/economy/us-posts-solid-job-gains-amid-fears.html?pagewanted=all}} 
Text.\pagenote{\emph{US Posts Stronger Solid Growth in July}, Mokoto Rich, 2011. The New York Times.\\\url{http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/06/business/economy/us-posts-solid-job-gains-amid-fears.html?pagewanted=all}} 
Text.\pagenote{\emph{US Posts Stronger Solid Growth in July}, Mokoto Rich, 2011. The New York Times.\\\url{http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/06/business/economy/us-posts-solid-job-gains-amid-fears.html?pagewanted=all}} 
Text.\pagenote{\emph{US Posts Stronger Solid Growth in July}, Mokoto Rich, 2011. The New York Times.\\\url{http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/06/business/economy/us-posts-solid-job-gains-amid-fears.html?pagewanted=all}} 
Text.\pagenote{\emph{US Posts Stronger Solid Growth in July}, Mokoto Rich, 2011. The New York Times.\\\url{http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/06/business/economy/us-posts-solid-job-gains-amid-fears.html?pagewanted=all}} 

\printpagenotes*

\backmatter
\clearpage


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your code, you create a new list with *every* page note that is displayed. In fact, the visible enumeration is completely separate from the list itself, hence the page break between the numbering and the actual page note.

Instead of trying to fit your page notes into the generic realm that [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) provides, I've modified the base function `\mem@printpagenotes` (called by `\printpagenotes`) to set the contents of the notes file within an `enumerate`, and each item in the file is set using `\item`.

[image]

```
% Document size 
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt,openright]{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\setstocksize{216mm}{154mm}
\settrimmedsize{215mm}{153mm}{*}
\settrims{1mm}{1mm}
\setulmarginsandblock{20mm}{22mm}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{22mm}{15mm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\trimLmarks

% Packages
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false,pdfborder=0 0 0}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{endnotes}% http://ctan.org/pkg/endnotes

% Chapter titles
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage{fourier}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fourier
\makeatletter
\setlength\midchapskip{7pt}
\makechapterstyle{VZ21}{
  \renewcommand\chapnamefont{\Large\scshape}
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\Large\scshape\centering}
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\huge\bfseries\centering}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{7pt}   % used as indentation on both sides
    \settowidth\@tempdimc{\chaptitlefont ##1}%
    \setlength\@tempdimc{\textwidth-\@tempdimc-2\tabcolsep}%
\chaptitlefont
\ifdim\@tempdimc > 0pt\relax    % one line
\begin{tabular}{c}
  \toprule  ##1\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\else   % two+ lines
\begin{tabular}{
    >{\chaptitlefont\arraybackslash}p{\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
  \toprule ##1\\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\fi }
}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{VZ21}

% Fix \url width
\renewcommand{\UrlBreaks}{\do\/\do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j\do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t\do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D\do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N\do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X\do\Y\do\Z}

\linespread{1.1}

% Fix pagenotes
\let\pagenote=\endnote

\makepagenote

\renewcommand\notesname{Notes}

% Section title
\setsecheadstyle{\large\uppercase}

\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[3]{\section*{#1 #2\ --\ #3}}
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubheadstarred}[3]{\section*{#3}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\mem@printpagenotes[1]{%
  \ifmempagenotes
    \notedivision% <--- Denotes \chapter
    \IfFileExists{\jobname.ent}{%
      \begingroup
      \mem@make@gt@safe%
      \def\startnoteentry####1####2####3####4>{%
        \begingroup
        \@ResetGT
        \item[####1.]%
      }
      \def\endnoteentry{\endnoteentryend\endgroup}
      \immediate\closeout\@notefile
      \vspace*{-2\baselineskip}% Remove large skip after \chapter
      \begin{enumerate}[nosep]% <--- start list here
      \input{\jobname.ent}% Read page notes
      \end{enumerate}% <--- end list here
      \if#1\immediate\openout\@notefile=\jobname.ent\fi%
      \endgroup
    }{%
      \mempnofilewarn
    }%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{headings}


Text.\pagenote{\emph{US Posts Stronger Solid Growth in July}, Mokoto Rich, 2011. The New York Times.\emph{US Posts Stronger Solid Growth in July}, Mokoto Rich, 2011. The New York Times.\emph{US Posts Stronger Solid Growth in July}, Mokoto Rich, 2011. The New York Times.\\\url{http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/06/business/economy/us-posts-solid-job-gains-amid-fears.html?pagewanted=all}} 
Text.\pagenote{\emph{US Posts Stronger Solid Growth in July}, Mokoto Rich, 2011. The New York Times.\\\url{http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/06/business/economy/us-posts-solid-job-gains-amid-fears.html?pagewanted=all}} 
Text.\pagenote{\emph{US Posts Stronger Solid Growth in July}, Mokoto Rich, 2011. The New York Times.\\\url{http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/06/business/economy/us-posts-solid-job-gains-amid-fears.html?pagewanted=all}} 
Text.\pagenote{\emph{US Posts Stronger Solid Growth in July}, Mokoto Rich, 2011. The New York Times.\\\url{http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/06/business/economy/us-posts-solid-job-gains-amid-fears.html?pagewanted=all}} 
Text.\pagenote{\emph{US Posts Stronger Solid Growth in July}, Mokoto Rich, 2011. The New York Times.\\\url{http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/06/business/economy/us-posts-solid-job-gains-amid-fears.html?pagewanted=all}} 
Text.\pagenote{\emph{US Posts Stronger Solid Growth in July}, Mokoto Rich, 2011. The New York Times.\\\url{http://www.nytimes.com/2011/08/06/business/economy/us-posts-solid-job-gains-amid-fears.html?pagewanted=all}} 

\printpagenotes*

\backmatter
\clearpage


\end{document}
```